# Stack services not allowing access to mapped ports

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop, docker-network

I started having problems (today) with my stack services not allowing access to mapped ports.  This is Docker Desktop 4.24.0 (122432) on Ubuntu (latest updates).  I won't go through all of my services, but here are two contains in my stack that are no longer accessible.

```
  a-service:
    image: private-repo/services-a:1.0.0
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "6522:8080"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - devnet

  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0.6
    ports:
      - "6517:27017"
    networks:
      - devnet
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
```

Taking a peek at the services:

```
$ docker stack services dev-stack 
ID             NAME                          MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                            PORTS
mdo7sfx54cjp   dev-stack_a-service           replicated   2/2        private-repo/services-a:1.0.0                    *:6522->8080/tcp
lx1po9lkg5zo   dev-stack_mongo               replicated   1/1        mongo:5.0.6                                      *:6517->27017/tcp
```

A-Service container logs (truncated):

```
$ docker container logs ab98faac8b80
[2023-10-12T17:08:38.863+0000] [] [INFO] [] [PayaraMicro] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1697130518863] [levelValue: 800] [[
  
Payara Micro URLs:Payara Micro URLs:
http://172.18.0.12:8080/a

'a-service-1.0.0' REST Endpoints:
GET /a/api/v1/status

]]
```

Mongo container logs (truncated):

```
$ docker container logs 037307ce2bd6
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T17:08:00.043+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T17:08:00.043+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T17:08:00.043+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T17:09:00.039+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1697130540:39225][1:0x7f7101625700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 3, snapshot max: 3 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 4726"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T17:10:00.048+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1697130600:48660][1:0x7f7101625700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 6, snapshot max: 6 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 4726"}}
```

Testing connections/endpoints:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6522/a/api/v1/status
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

$ mongosh mongodb://localhost:6517
Current Mongosh Log ID: 65282973340b5cbff1e035fa
Connecting to:      mongodb://localhost:6517/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 2000 ms
```

Looking at listening ports:

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 6522
tcp6       0      0 :::6522                 :::*                    LISTEN      3855/com.docker.bac 

$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 6517
tcp6       0      0 :::6517                 :::*                    LISTEN      3855/com.docker.bac 

$ sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 6522
com.docke 3855            john   34u  IPv6 137484      0t0  TCP *:6522 (LISTEN)

$ sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 6517
com.docke 3855            john  171u  IPv6 115531      0t0  TCP *:6517 (LISTEN)
```

I don't see anything for IPv4.

```
$ docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2-desktop.5
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.22.0-desktop.2
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.20
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.8
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-init
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.26.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan
  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.7
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout

Server:
 Containers: 52
  Running: 47
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 50
 Server Version: 24.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: kb213yi4lkr3kx5fetf7aidtp
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: k3vutzcr0275nxf7wk9z0f32y
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 192.168.65.4
  Manager Addresses:
   192.168.65.4:2377
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc version: v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.4.16-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 24.47GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 9a107382-34ae-4617-a241-b1b940f141a3
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Username: jmankoago
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  private-repo
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with Docker Desktop 4.24.0+.  Rolling back to 4.23.0 solved my problem.